# PartialView $('#webgrid').html(data) causes webgrid col click to display only the grid & w/o css?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am doing some partial page updates with WebGrid in MVC3 but when I update my grid with $('#grid').html(data) and then click on a col/link in the grid to sort by that column my page get's reloaded with just the grid in a non-css format.  How can I fix this?

**Index.cshtml**

```
 // ...
 // grid partial view
 <div id="gridview" class="gen">@Html.Partial("_gridPartialView", Model.Data)</div>

// On button click on main page to get filtered data to new grid
$.get('@Url.Action("GetFilteredData")', { 'statusFilter': filterstuff }, function (data) {
   $('#gridview').html(data);
});
```

**_gridPartialView.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<.Models.Data>
@{           
  var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model,
  //defaultSort: "DataId",
             rowsPerPage: 50);                     
}
@grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "webgrid",
    headerStyle: "head",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("DataId", "Id"),
    grid.Column("DataName", "Name"),
    //...
```

**Controller ActionResult:**

```
public ActionResult GetFilteredData(int[] statusFilter)
{
   // Do filtered query on data model
   return PartialView("_gridPartialView", cvm.Campaigns);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your **_gridPartialView.cshtml** Change your grid declaration to something like :

```
 var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model,
    //defaultSort: "DataId",
    ajaxUpdateCallback: "GridUpdate",
    ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid"
    rowsPerPage: 50);
```

ensure that your .GetHtml method has :

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" }, 
//.. rest of the options here
)
```

and add the below to your **Index.cshtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GridUpdate(data) {
        $('#gridview').html(data);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thx for the post. $$$$ - Spot on! :)

Comment: QQ, one thing that I notice is that the first time the grid loads per the main Index() call (before any fitlering updates get applied to the grid) when I click on a col link to to sort my grid get's injected with the entire page contents.

Comment: Not sure if that's what you mean but maybe adding following code to your partial view will fix it ?
@{
   Layout = null; 
}